# Is it possible to startActivityForResult on 2nd child?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main activity from which I can start other activity (confirmSMS) and from confirmSMS I start activity emergencySMS. Is it possible to access result of emergencySMS activity in main activity? Right now I have tried starting confirmSMS as basic startActivity (nohistory is set to true) and then starting emergencySMS from confirmSMS as activityforresult but this aproach is apparently not working.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible

1. Start activity confirmSMS for result.
2. Then Start activity emergencySMS for result.
3. when emergencySMS's work is done return result and finish this activity.
4. Capture the result in confirmSMS Activity and finish this activity also.
5. Return the result to main activity.

Comment: hmm, this aproach should work but I think there is a problem with nohistory set to true on confirmSMS. It looks like my result never gets to confirmSMS from emergencySMS

Comment: Let the confirmSMS Activity be at resume state. And finish it when you get the result. And this approach will work fine. I have implemented it my self.

Comment: For NO history you can also check from where you are comming to this activity and can handle the situation]

Answer (score 1):

You can start confirmSMS activity as startActivityForResult and onNotificationResult you forward to main activity the received result from emergencySMS activity